# Access SQL - Update Table A Where ID NOT in Table B

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, both have the same unique key (Case).

I want to update a field in table A (Master) where the unique key (Case) doesn't exist in Table B (Extract)

```
    UPDATE Master SET [Date Closed] = (Date())
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Extract
                  WHERE Master.Case = Extract.Case
                 );
```

This isn't giving an error but it is taking several minutes to run, so is the query correct and if so can it be improved to run more quickly.

I have around 90k records in Master and 60k in Extract so I wouldn't expect it to take more than a few seconds to run, am I being optimistic, or is my query wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query

```
UPDATE Master SET [Date Closed] = (Date())
WHERE Master.Case NOT IN (SELECT Extract.Case FROM Extract)
```